# Pars Script to find special value with Beautifuo soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have this script:

```
var s1 = new SWFObject('/media/player/flvplayer.swf','single','400','300','7');s1.addParam('allowfullscreen','true');s1.addVariable('file','http://cdn.abc.con/video.flv');s1.addParam('menu','false');s1.addVariable('width','400');s1.addVariable('height','300');s1.write('player1474719921904');
```

I m going to get the video url value:

`http://cdn.abc.con/video.flv`

i tried this, but can't found that:

```
scripts = soup.find_all("script")
        if scripts:
            for s in scripts:
                crawler_logger.info('s: %s' % s)
                l = s.find_all(attrs={'': re.compile(r'\.(flv|mp4)$')})
```

I want to be able to get all videos like this, without need to knowing url name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BeautifulSoup doesn't parse javascript. From your script tag `s`, extract the javascript code as:

```
code = s.text
```

Then you can extract the URL manually with regexes like so:

```
import re

code = """var s1 = new SWFObject('/media/player/flvplayer.swf','single','400','300','7');s1.addParam('allowfullscreen','true');s1.addVariable('file','http://cdn.abc.con/video.flv');s1.addParam('menu','false');s1.addVariable('width','400');s1.addVariable('height','300');s1.write('player1474719921904');"""
url = re.search(r"['\"](https?://.+?\.flv)['\"]", code).group(1)
print(url)   # http://cdn.abc.con/video.flv
```

Comment: can you please tell me how to get url video as a parameter, I mean that i i can be able to get the url with out knowing its absolute path, something `every url with exists in there`

Comment: @SajadHTLO I've made the regex more general. Consider `re.findall` as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
    import re

    text = '''
    var s1 = new SWFObject('/media/player/flvplayer.swf','single','400','300','7');s1.addParam('allowfullscreen','true');s1.addVariable('file','http://cdn.abc.con/video.flv');s1.addParam('menu','false');s1.addVariable('width','400');s1.addVariable('height','300');s1.write('player1474719921904');
    var s1 = new SWFObject('/media/player/flvplayer.swf','single','400','300','7');s1.addParam('allowfullscreen','true');s1.addVariable('file','http://cdn.abc.con/video.flv');s1.addParam('menu','false');s1.addVariable('width','400');s1.addVariable('height','300');s1.write('player1474719921904');
    var s1 = new SWFObject('/media/player/flvplayer.swf','single','400','300','7');s1.addParam('allowfullscreen','true');s1.addVariable('file','http://cdn.abc.con/video.flv');s1.addParam('menu','false');s1.addVariable('width','400');s1.addVariable('height','300');s1.write('player1474719921904');
    '''
    link = re.findall(r"'(http.+?)'", text)
    print(link)
```

out:

```
['http://cdn.abc.con/video.flv', 'http://cdn.abc.con/video.flv', 'http://cdn.abc.con/video.flv']
```

this regex will find all the link, and put them in a list